# Bootstrap-Table: Filter Control with multiple inputs for the same data-field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Is there a way to achieve a filter with two or more inputs for the same column/data-field?

Example (think about Forename and Surname but the column you want to filter has both included): https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/chsteiner/10891

It works but the input fields get messed up in the process.

Answer (score 1):

This new feature was recently added. You can see the Fix/Feature [in GitHub](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/pull/6301)

You will now be able to filter by more than one value in the same column using a delimiter. The release should occur soon.